# What is the probability that we get more than $\frac{n}{2} + 2\sqrt{nln(n)}$ heads?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Toss $n$ coins. What is the probability that we get more than $\frac{n}{2} + 2\sqrt{n[\ln(n)]}$ heads?

How do I apply Chernoff Bounds to this?

I really need help understanding Chernoff Bounds.

Comment: Merge might be a better option than closing as duplicate.